# Perspective issue in 3D Rotation

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, core-animation, catransform3d

I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

Which is a snapshot of my view controller

The code I have tried is like this:

```
    UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

    // Take a snapshot
    //
    _screenshotView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull];

    _screenshotView.image = [self getScreenSnapshot];

    _screenshotView.frame = CGRectMake(-160, -284, _screenshotView.image.size.width, _screenshotView.image.size.height);
    _screenshotView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    _screenshotView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);

    _originalSize = _screenshotView.frame.size;

    [window addSubview:_screenshotView];

    [self minimizeFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, _originalSize.width, _originalSize.height)];


- (void)minimizeFromRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    CGFloat m = 0.7;
    CGFloat newWidth = _originalSize.width * m;
    CGFloat newHeight = _originalSize.height * m;

    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.6] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];
    [self addAnimation:@"position.x" view:_screenshotView startValue:rect.origin.x endValue:window.frame.size.width - 80.0];
    [self addAnimation:@"position.y" view:_screenshotView startValue:rect.origin.y endValue:(window.frame.size.height - newHeight) / 2.0];
    [self addAnimation:@"bounds.size.width" view:_screenshotView startValue:rect.size.width endValue:newWidth];
    [self addAnimation:@"bounds.size.height" view:_screenshotView startValue:rect.size.height endValue:newHeight];

    _screenshotView.layer.position = CGPointMake(window.frame.size.width - 80.0, (window.frame.size.height - newHeight) / 2.0);
    _screenshotView.layer.bounds = CGRectMake(window.frame.size.width - 80.0, (window.frame.size.height - newHeight) / 2.0, newWidth, newHeight);

    CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -600;
    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, -20.0f * M_PI / 180.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    _screenshotView.layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;

    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

The code works fine except that it looks like the rotation is shown from a different perspective because the snapshot after animation turns out to be like this:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by replacing `UIImageView` object with `CALayer` image layer object.
Thanks to https://github.com/kristopherjohnson/perspectivetest

```
    UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

    // Take a snapshot
    //

    UIImage *image = [self getScreenSnapshot];
    CGImageRef pictureImage = image.CGImage;

    CGFloat zDistance = 1200.0f;
    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform.m34 = 1.0f / -zDistance;

    _screenshotView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull];
    _screenshotView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    _screenshotView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    _imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
    _imageLayer.frame = _screenshotView.frame;;
    _imageLayer.contents = (__bridge id)pictureImage;
    _imageLayer.transform = transform;

    [_screenshotView.layer addSublayer:_imageLayer];

    _originalSize = _screenshotView.frame.size;

    [window addSubview:_screenshotView];

    [self minimizeFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, _originalSize.width, _originalSize.height)];


- (void)minimizeFromRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    CGFloat m = 0.6;
    CGFloat newWidth = _originalSize.width * m;
    CGFloat newHeight = _originalSize.height * m;

    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.4] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];
    [self addAnimation:@"position.x" view:_screenshotView startValue:rect.origin.x endValue:window.frame.size.width - 40.0];
    [self addAnimation:@"position.y" view:_screenshotView startValue:rect.origin.y endValue:(window.frame.size.height - newHeight) / 2.0];
    [self addAnimation:@"bounds.size.width" view:_screenshotView startValue:rect.size.width endValue:newWidth];
    [self addAnimation:@"bounds.size.height" view:_screenshotView startValue:rect.size.height endValue:newHeight];
    [self addAnimationForLayer:@"transform.rotation.y" view:_imageLayer startValue:0.0f endValue:-0.4 * M_PI];


    _screenshotView.layer.position = CGPointMake(window.frame.size.width - 80.0, (window.frame.size.height - newHeight) / 2.0);
    _screenshotView.layer.bounds = CGRectMake(window.frame.size.width - 80.0, (window.frame.size.height - newHeight) / 2.0, newWidth, newHeight);

    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way around could be that you can use two images, one for upper half and one for lower half. And you can stitch the two images together so that the gap is not visible and you can get the desired output.

Set the property to one positive and one negative value for upper and one lower image or vice verse. You can get the two images of desired result. Then you can set the frame to make them stick together so that they look as one image.

Property :: `rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / 600.0;`

Property :: `rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = -1.0 / 600.0;`

You might need to do some hit and trial.

Comment: To do it right away you need to make the rotation in more than 2 planes. For eg - In Y and Z. And you need to test and make it proper by setting different angles. What you are doing is only from the Y axis.

Comment: cant get what you're upto, but Ive already solved it by applying animation directly to CALayer object, see the marked answer